# How to change minimum deployment iosTarget from Codemagic?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, codemagic

I have developed a Flutter App on Windows. Now I am trying to make the build via codemagic. But I need to change the minimum deployment version for IOS. 
I get this error while building app with codemagic

> Specs satisfying the `stripe_payment (from`.symlinks/plugins/stripe_payment/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: what version of `stripe_payment` do you use?

Comment: stripe_payment: ^1.0.6

Comment: Hi @HamzaAzam, you can use VNC access to macOS computer on Codemagic and setup Xcode settings for your project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to define the minimum platform ios version in the `Podfile` file.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

**Note:** the `Podfile` will be created once you run `flutter build ios`.

### If you don't have a macOS device

You'll have to run `flutter build ios` on a macOS device. If you don't have such a device you can create a CI build pipeline for your project (on Azure Devops for example), and run the CI build on a macOS agent.

In the pipeline you have to add a step that uploads the `Podfile` to an artifact, so you can download that artifact and add the `Podfile` to your sources.

**Note:** [here](https://github.com/FlorisDevreese/Flutter-CI-CD/tree/master) you'll find a simple CI/CD build example for building your Flutter app for `IOS` and `Android` without the need for a `macOS` device.

Comment: I tried your Podfile but it takes an hour to build and it keeps on building. is there a way to make Podfile logging verbose?

Comment: @Clueless I don't know :-/

Comment: I can confirm it works. I also ran pod install in the terminal afterward!

Comment: I have this minimum deployment version set in my podfile (set to 10), but the app store still shows compatibility with 9.0. Any idea why?

Comment: @MatthewRideout, sorry don't know. Not working in this space anymore

Comment: In Latest, flutter stripe version 6.0.0 changes the platform: ios to 12

Answer (score 5):

I tried changing minimum target to 10.0 but it was still complaining.
I set to

> platform :ios, '13.0'

worked fine for me